# Adding a JTextarea to a JScrollPane. What to visible, the 1st or the 2nd?

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am making a form in Java and I want to visualize a text area with a scrollbar, the problem is that I change multiple times the `.setVisible()` value from true to false and vice versa and I don't know what to change, the scroll pane or the text area?

For example:

```java
    public void pantallaInicio() {  
        imagen.setVisible(false);  
        existencia_lb.setVisible(false);
        subtotal_lb.setVisible(false); ... }
//And I also have this one: 
    public void pantallaAgregar() { 
        imagen.setVisible(true);
        existencia_lb.setVisible(true);
        subtotal_lb.setVisible(true); ...}
// Here is where I don't know if I should change the ScrollPane or the TextArea value.
```

Comment: Are you coding by hand or using a GUI builder? The actual answer is *neither*. setVisible() is typically called on a JFrame or JPanel. Why are you playing with setVisible() at the component level? What are you actually trying to achieve? The more descriptive you are, the more accurate the help will be.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Yes I am coding by hand, I am creating a Form and I have multiple screens where I just hide the elements that I don't want to visualize. For example:
 `public void pantallaInicio() {
       imagen.setVisible(false);
        existencia_lb.setVisible(false);
        subtotal_lb.setVisible(false); ...
}`
And I also have this one:
`public void pantallaAgregar() {
        imagen.setVisible(true);
        existencia_lb.setVisible(true);
        subtotal_lb.setVisible(true)
}`
Here is where I don't know if I should change the ScrollPane or the TextArea value.

Comment: Put the scrollPane and textArea into a JPanel and call setVisible on that so that they both go away or show up at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what to change, the scroll pane or the text area

Neither. Add the text area to the scroll pane when it is constructed. Add the scroll pane to the GUI. When the top level window (usually a `JFrame`) is set visible, both the text area and scroll pane will be visible.